# How can I tell when the background (i.e. not a cell) is touched on a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I've tried subclassing UICollectionView and overriding `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `hitTest:WithEvent:`, and both of those methods trigger when I touch a cell.  However, if I touch the space between the cells, nothing happens at all.  Here's what I've created:

```
@interface WSImageGalleryCollectionView : UICollectionView
@end
```

..and..

```
@implementation WSImageGalleryCollectionView

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Touches began");
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Hit test reached");
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

*Note: gesture recognizers seem to have the exact same issue, which is why I tried going lower-level with touchesBegan.*

Comment: What happens when you put the UICollectionView inside a container UIView, and then override touchesBegan, moved, etc on the container view? . . otherwise, it wouldn't be too hard to write a custom collection view, i think.

Answer (score 12):

You just need to set a view as background view that you can then add a gesture recognizer to like:

```
collectionView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[collectionView.backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnBackgroundRecognized)]];
```

Comment: Thanks @Micael Loistl, it woks with me

Answer (score 0):

You must have got something else that is preventing `touchesBegan` from firing.

Subclassing `UICollectionView` and using that subclass inside of a `UICollectionViewController` will allow you to detect in-between cells taps in `touchesBegan`.

I have just tried it out by modifying Apple's [CollectionView-simple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012860)  sample.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that you can click on the background whenever it is "clear" colored.  Otherwise simply setting a background color makes the background clickable.  I don't quite know why this is, but the simple fix was to just give it a background color.

Edit:  Actually, this may have had something to do with setting the "opaque" flag.